# How to decide at runtime which types `from_le_bytes` should be called?

Tags: rust

I want to read a file type that contains some header metadata and array of homogeneous data and store it in a vector.

Something like this:

```
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn main() {
    // Pretend that `bytes` came from the output of reading a file at runtime
    let bytes: Vec<u8> = vec![34, 23, 42, 233, 23, 56, 23, 65, 33, 23, 56, 76];

    // Pretend that `float32_or_int16` came from reading a file at runtime
    let float32_or_int16 = "float32";

    let size_of_type;
    match float32_or_int16 {
        "float32" => {
            size_of_type = 4;
        }
        "int16" => {
            size_of_type = 2;
        }
        &_ => {
            panic!();
        }
    }

    let mut output_vec = Vec::new();

    for factor in 0..bytes.len() / size_of_type {
        let start_index = factor * size_of_type;

        let num_slice = &bytes[start_index..start_index + size_of_type];
        let num_array = num_slice.try_into().unwrap();

        // Need to make this part generic
        let final_num = f32::from_le_bytes(num_array); //TODO make me generic

        output_vec.push(final_num); //TODO make me generic
    }

    println!("{:?}", output_vec);
}
```

The issue is that the type of this homogeneous data can differ from one file to the next i.e one file may store an array of `f64` while other may store an array of `i8`. Exactly which type is stored in the header metadata.

Note that since the data in the file is homogeneous technically the `output_vec` only needs to store one data type. Also note that this is a simple example in reality there are going to be many more types, making the need for some generic solution more important.

Another complication is that the final output needs to be fed to the 'nalgebra' crate which i think might further limit my options. Though that's a headache for another time.

I tried `union` and `enum` based dynamic dispatch and honestly I don't even know why but it didn't work. In order to not make this question too long I think it's best I don't paste my `enum`s attempt since it dosen't really work anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well to use a generic, you'd have to extract your logic into a function, with the help of [`num_traits::FromBytes`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/ops/bytes/trait.FromBytes.html#) for a trait that gives us a generic `from_le_bytes` that isn't too hard:

```rust
fn main() {
    // Pretend that `bytes` came from the output of reading a file at runtime
    let bytes: Vec<u8> = vec![34, 23, 42, 233, 23, 56, 23, 65, 33, 23, 56, 76];

    // Pretend that `float32_or_int16` came from reading a file at runtime
    let float32_or_int16 = "float32";
    match float32_or_int16 {
        "float32" => {
            let output_vec = to_vec::<f32>(&bytes);
            dbg!(&output_vec);
        }
        "int16" => {
            let output_vec = to_vec::<i16>(&bytes);
            dbg!(&output_vec);
        }
        _ => panic!(),
    }
}

fn to_vec<T>(bytes: &[u8]) -> Vec<T>
where
    T: num_traits::FromBytes,
    for<'a> &'a [u8]: TryInto<&'a T::Bytes>,
{
    bytes
        .chunks_exact(std::mem::size_of::<T>())
        .map(TryInto::<&T::Bytes>::try_into)
        .map(|x| x.unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("could not convert slice to array reference!")))
        .map(T::from_le_bytes)
        .collect()
}
```

Comment: it works! Thanks! 
Would it be possible to get output_vec outside of the scope of the match block. Otherwise i think i would end up having duplicate a lot of stuff or to be forced to make mega functions.

Comment: @Zero as it has different types in each case you can't really. You can put your code into a generic function or wrap it in an `enum` though.